# Netsuite Advanced PDF BOM

Tags: pdf, freemarker, netsuite, bfo

I am creating a print out for BOM using advanced pdf. I am trying to get get the value of the Start Date from the work order but in the print out, it is empty. I set this using ${record.startdate}. Is this correct? Is there another internal id for start date and end date in the work order?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not workout Print Pdf in Work order.  Just  use  this code ${workorder.startdate}

Answer (score 1):

If the object passed to the pdf generator name is "record" offcourse you can reference is as it is. It depends on the passed parameter name. If you are modifying existing html check the rest of the script and you will see if its 'record' or not.

You can reference with `${record.startDate}` and `${record.endDate}`

All the available fields for the object can be found [here](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2017_1/schema/record/workorder.html).